# getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view, layout); does not cover entire actionbar

Tags: android-layout, android-custom-view, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to set a custom actionbar background but it does not fill up the entire space.
it leaves like a 5dp grey actionbar from left side.
I used the following:

```
 android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view, layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

this is my custom actionbar xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
    ></RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried different styles but none worked.
please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixed it by doing:

```
//to set same background color on entire actiobar
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_color));

//to display custom layout with same BG color
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view, layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: what is 'view' that you passed in setCustomView(view, layout)?